# How to calculate percentage using sql request

Tags: mysql, sql

I'am using mysql5.

I want to calcucate a percentage using SQL request, but I couldn't do that.

I want to calculate a percentage for each environment, but I could just calculate a 
percentage for an environment.

I have wrote two sql statements, one returns the number of success test having OK results and the second returns the total number of success test.

Each of them work fine but I couldn't using them in the same statement to calculate percentage.

The first SQL statement:

```
SELECT count(result.success),
       result.RESULT_ENV
FROM result, 
     scenario,
     env
WHERE result.RESULT_ENV = env.ENV_URL
AND scenario.PHASE_ID = result.RESULT_PHASE
AND scenario.PHASE_ID = "availibility"
AND result.TIME BETWEEN '2011-07-14 12:00:00' AND '2011-07-15 10:12:59' 
AND result.TIME NOT BETWEEN 
    (
        SELECT MW_DB 
        FROM mw 
        WHERE MW_DB  BETWEEN '2011-07-14 12:00:00' AND '2011-07-15 10:12:59'
    ) AND 
    (
        SELECT MW_DF 
        FROM mw 
        WHERE MW_DB BETWEEN '2011-07-14 12:00:00' AND '2011-07-15 10:00:55'
    )
AND result.SUCCESS = "ok" 
GROUP BY result.RESULT_ENV
```

Return:

```
number  |     RESULT_ENV
--------+------------------
  6     |    http://somip1
  1     |    http://somip2
```

The second SQL statement:

```
SELECT count(result.success),
       result.RESULT_ENV
FROM result, 
     scenario,
     env
WHERE result.RESULT_ENV = env.ENV_URL
AND scenario.PHASE_ID = result.RESULT_PHASE
AND scenario.PHASE_ID = "availibility"
AND result.TIME BETWEEN '2011-07-14 12:00:00' AND '2011-07-15 10:12:59' 
AND result.TIME NOT BETWEEN 
    (
        SELECT MW_DB 
        FROM mw 
        WHERE MW_DB  BETWEEN '2011-07-14 12:00:00' AND '2011-07-15 10:12:59'
    ) AND 
    (
        SELECT MW_DF 
        FROM mw 
        WHERE MW_DB BETWEEN '2011-07-14 12:00:00' AND '2011-07-15 10:00:55'
    )
GROUP BY result.RESULT_ENV
```

Return:

```
number  |     RESULT_ENV
--------+------------------
  8     |    http://somip1
  2     |    http://somip2
```

The result should be:

```
percent |     RESULT_ENV
--------+------------------
  75    |    http://somip1
  50    |    http://somip2
```

Comment: Confusingly worded, not fully specified question. Impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [CASE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) like that :

```
(100 * SUM(CASE WHEN result.SUCCESS = 'ok' THEN 1 ELSE 0)) / COUNT(result.success)
```

Then your query must be something like that :

```
SELECT (100 * SUM(CASE WHEN result.SUCCESS = 'ok' THEN 1 ELSE 0)) / COUNT(result.success),
       result.RESULT_ENV
FROM result, 
     scenario,
     env
WHERE result.RESULT_ENV = env.ENV_URL
AND scenario.PHASE_ID = result.RESULT_PHASE
AND scenario.PHASE_ID = "availibility"
AND result.TIME BETWEEN '2011-07-14 12:00:00' AND '2011-07-15 10:12:59' 
AND result.TIME NOT BETWEEN 
    (
        SELECT MW_DB 
        FROM mw 
        WHERE MW_DB  BETWEEN '2011-07-14 12:00:00' AND '2011-07-15 10:12:59'
    ) AND 
    (
        SELECT MW_DF 
        FROM mw 
        WHERE MW_DB BETWEEN '2011-07-14 12:00:00' AND '2011-07-15 10:00:55'
    )
GROUP BY result.RESULT_ENV
```

[See the doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html).